# Drupal 7 Solr 4 $query group by

Tags: search

I'm beginner in Drupal 7 et Solr 4. I have $query and I want to do a group by category. How can I add 'group by' as a parameter to $query (DrupalSolrQueryInterface) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. In the view of Apache Solr, I enter the parameter and and add the field of group by. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom parameters through [`hook_apachesolr_query_alter`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7), eg

```
function MYMODULE_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $query->addParam('group', 'true');
  // etc
}
```

Comment: I try your proposition, but, an error message display: 
Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator.

Comment: That's just a basic example, you probably need `group.field` etc as extra parameters as well. Whatever you would add to the normal Solr query string to get your desired results, add that as a parameter. Your error logs will contain more information to help

Comment: Can you give me an example with addParam('group', 'true') ??